# Make Kafka Consumer wait for Events

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a use case where a consumer needs to listen to some events on a topic T1(consumesmessages in topic T1 and search for certain cases) .Only if it detect certain events then start consuming from topic T2 and  work on the messages retrieved from T2.We are using spring kafka 2.1.7.I do not see a way to do this now
as consumer would start reading from T2 as  the kafkalistener  bean for it comes up .I am looking for suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `@KafkaListener` should rely on slightly different `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` instances where one for the topic `T2` should be configured with the `setAutoStartup(false)`.

So, when condition in the `@KafkaListener` for `T1` is met, you call a `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(containerId).start()` for the second `@KafkaLisnter`. The `containerId` comes from the `@KafkaLisnter.id()`.

Comment: In the next release (2.2) you will be able to override the `autoStartup` directly on the `@KafkaListener` annotation.

Comment: Thanks folks.Overriding autostartup on listener would be very helpful.Meanwhile one of the additional requirement is that the offset commit to topic T2 and topic T1 should be within the same transaction. So my understanding here is  that I cannot let the  container manage
 the transaction until 2.2 is out but use the same transaction manager @ method level and then use template.sendOffsetsToTransaction for both T1 and T2 .Is that the right way?

Comment: I don't think so. The second `@KafkaListener` is going to work in its own thread. I think you can't send offsets for committing to the other thread.